# Is the fact that quantum mechanic theory follows probabilistic laws directly connected to the fact that the energy levels are quantified?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In the theory of quantum mechanics theory (would it be a correct or incorrect theory), is the fact that quantum mechanic theory follows probabilistic laws directly *connected* ("bijection") to the fact that the energy levels are quantified in this theory ?

- Could a theory manage to have discret levels while determinist laws ?
- Could a theory manage to have probabilistic laws but continuous energy levels ?

Comment: What kind of theory do you think of? A free non-relativistic quantum particle has a purly contineous energy spectrum. Is this the kind of examples you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware

Comment: Than I may add that the interesting thing about QM is that, in contrast to classical mechanics, a observable can have a contineous and a discrite set of possible values simultaneously. Take for example the Hydrogen atom with its discrete bound state energy levels. At the same time, it posesses a contineoum of levels for an unbound electron (sometimes called scattering states).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that QM follows probabilistic laws is connected to something called commutation.

Fundametally there is no such thing as discrete energy levels.So no. **(explaination below)**\

**Could a theory manage to have discret levels while determinist laws ?**
yes a train moving on a track cannot deviate(stable state).

**Could a theory manage to have probabilistic laws but continuous energy levels ?**
Assuming you are talking about uncertainity principle then no it is what,that really is quantum specific but w.r.t only certain observables , (even in QM position of a particle along different axis can be known accurately),again Energy is always continous.

**Now coming to explaination .**

Firstly free electron doesn't have discrete energy levels after applying quantum mechanics.

Taking electron as an example what we mean by discrete energy is like this([source](https://wtamu.edu/%7Ecbaird/sq/2014/06/18/how-can-an-electron-leap-between-atomic-levels-without-passing-through-all-the-space-in-between/))

Quantum theory tells us that an electron with a "stationary energy" can only exist at certain, discrete energy levels. This distinction is very important. By "stationary energy" we mean that the electron's energy stays constant for a fairly long period of time. The orbitals of a particular atom are not the only allowed states that an electron can take on in the atom. They are the only "stable states" of the atom, meaning that when an electron settles down to a particular state in an atom, it must be in one of the orbital states.

When an electron is in the process of transitioning between stable states, it is not itself stable and therefore has less restrictions on its energy. In fact, an electron that transitions does not even have a well-defined energy. Innate quantum uncertainty arises in the electron's energy because of its transition. The quicker an electron transitions, the more uncertain its energy. This "innate quantum uncertainty" is not some metaphysical mystery, but is better understood as the wave spreading out over many values. Just as the electron can spread out into a wave that extends over a region of space, it can also spread out into a wave that extends over a region along the energy scale. If you calculate the average energy (the "expectation value") of this transitioning electron's spread of energies, you find that the electron's average energy does not instantaneously jump from one energy level to another. Rather, it smoothly transitions on average from the one energy level to the other energy level over a period of time.

If you want a better mental image, you can think of the electron as quickly, but smoothly sliding along the energy scale from one stable state to the next. Because a typical atomic electron transition is so fast (often on the order of nanoseconds), it can seem to be nearly instantaneous to the slow human senses, but fundamentally it is not.